# How to make Tornado server side really async

Tags: python, tornado

I start a long file-based db search which should run async and leave the browser side alone for other requests, but it seems that it blocks. What is the problem?

```
class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def initialize(self, param):
        self.db = param

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def post(self):
        try:
            self.set_status(200)
            response = yield gen.Task(self.handleSearch, self.request.arguments)
            self.finish(response)
        except BaseException, s:
            logging.exception(s)
            self.finish("Error tonight, cause: %s" % s)

    def handleSearch(self, request, callback):
        return callback(self.db.createList(request))
```

Comment: What does that mean, "leave the browser side alone [..], but it seems to block"?!

Comment: I have a html page which can send multiple requests to the server (e.g via buttons). When a search query runs, the rest of this page (e.g requests via other buttons) should be accessible,

Comment: So what is happening? How are you sending requests to the server? If the *client side* is blocking that sounds more like the *client side* isn't asynchronous...!?

Comment: A html button calls the following function

    function search(event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  var data;
  data = $(".o").serialize();

  $.post("seach",data,function(response) {
   document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = response     
   }
  });
 }

Comment: Please help: how can I pretty-print the code entered into a comment?

Comment: You cannot, [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use tornado async feature, your functions Needs to be async too,otherwise it's not really async

there are a few libraries for tornado out there, [check this out](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/wiki/Links) for libraries, but if you didn't find your needed library, another solution would be to use fantastic [future](http://pythonhosted.org/futures/)

so using future in python your code would be like this

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def initialize(self, param):
        self.db = param

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        self.set_status(200)
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(1) as execute:
            r = yield execute.submit(self.handleSearch, param=request.arguments)
            self.finish(r)

    def handleSearch(self, param):
        try:
            return self.db.createList(param) # or time.sleep(4) (sth which block)
        except Exception as e:
            return False
```

I already test it, and it works, it's 100% compatible with tornado so your not going to facing any issues

Comment: How can I return (or render) the result to the web-client?

Comment: it depends on tornado.web.RequestHandler, read this: http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#thread-safety-notes

Comment: I've tried self,write() but is does not work because at the end of the post() the connection is closed. The question is still: how can I send my result back.

Comment: My answer, is a good answer to your question, what you said in comment requires another question,but for sake of completely, you can use async timeout to prevent closing connection, there are plenty of timeout using tornado in stackoverflow or prevent tornado to closing connection itself.just a little search will do the job

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Lazac I updated my answer to exactly what you want, much better solution